# Grab a remote users HKLM using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to get another machine on your networks HKLM ?  I imagine you would use a pdrive for this but I was unable to get a command working successfully

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it but how you do it depends on the environment you have.

1) Probably the easiest way is to use invoke-command

```
Ex.
Invoke-command -computer RemoteComputerName {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\run}
```

This would work if you have sufficient permission on the remote machine, WinRM is configured for you to connect to it.

2) You can use .net registry classes
See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx

```
$registry = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', 'RemoteComputerName')
$registryKey= $registry.OpenSubKey("Software")
```

3) You use PSDrive as shown in the Scripting Guy blog
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/07/use-the-powershell-registry-provider-to-simplify-registry-access.aspx

4) You can use WMI Registry
http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/wmi-and-the-registry/

Comment: Trying the .NET route but it keeps giving me an error on GetValue saying that it's not a valid method.

Comment: The link to the ScriptingGuy blog in 3) is not there anymore. I think this is the new URL : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-the-powershell-registry-provider-to-simplify-registry-access/